# Will viewWillAppear get triggered if the view is already visible?

Tags: swift

Supposedly, there is a viewController A who calls viewController B. Now due to some business logic, there is also an API call whose completion handler triggers viewController B. Will the viewWillAppear be triggered again if it is already visible?

Comment: Add a print statement and check?

Comment: Well, I sure tried. Couldn't trigger the viewWillAppear if the view is already on screen. But I thought to understand better

Comment: In my experience, when viewWillAppear will be called is not consistently defined. While Apple claims "when it will be added to the view hierarchy," and this is probably mostly true, not all containers (tab views, navigation views, etc) carefully define when they adjust the hierarchy. In my experience, you need to test your particular case and see what happens. This is not ideal, and not 100% promised to stay consistent, though I haven't run into many cases of Apple changing it over the years. Best of luck. In my experience this is a murky area. "No" in this case feels right, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RobNapier! Appreciate your advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621510-viewwillappear):

> This method is called before the view controller's view is about to be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured for showing the view.

If you can already see the view, it's already been added to the hierarchy, meaning `ViewWillAppear` has already been called.

Comment: Thanks @ZGski. Appreciate your response